# Swift 3 Timer does not start from Notification

Tags: swift

I have a timer in ViewController using swift 3

```
var displayDataUpdateTimer = Timer()
```

The timer is triggered from a Notification from a socket in bridged Objective C code to the following observer in swift in ViewController, which calls the startDroTimer function, in the Viewcontroller

```
droUpdateObserver.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(startDroTimer), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "droUpdate"), object: nil)


func startDroTimer(notification:Notification){
    print("Message received to Start Display update")
    displayDataUpdateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3,target: self,selector: #selector(refreshDisplayData),userInfo: nil,repeats: true)
}
```

The notification arrives and the "Message received to Start Display update" is printed in the console, but the timer does not fire.

If I start the timer from a button

```
@IBAction func requestDisplayUpdate(_ sender: Any) {
    displayDataUpdateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3,target: self,selector: #selector(refreshDisplayData),userInfo: nil,repeats: true)
}
```

It fires consistently

Any suggestions what to try will be appreciated

Comment: Is the `startDroTime` method being called on the main thread or a background thread?

Comment: Yes, if the notification could be posted from a background queue, make sure to `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` the creation of the timer.